# Change encoding of XML file from ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-8

Tags: python, bash, character-encoding

I have an XML file that's in `ISO-8859-1` and I need it in `ISO-8859-8`
I know it's `ISO-8859-1` by using `file -i output.xml` and I get `charset=iso-8859-1`

The xml is generated using a python script that gets a csv file.

I've tried numerous ways:

### first way: python

I've tried using `encode` and `decode` on either of the input and output strings, and I keep getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position ... bla bla bla`

I've tried using `data.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('iso-8859-8')`
Or in the output method,

```
def write(data, output_file_name):
    with open(output_file_name, "wb") as output_file:
        output_file.write(data.encode('is-8859-8'))
```

and neither worked

### second way: bash

without any of the additional encoding code in python, this is the bash script I use

```
convertFileEncoding()
{
    local FILE_PATH=$1
    local SRC_ENC=$2
    local DEST_ENC=$3

    iconv -f $SRC_ENC -t $DESC_ENC//TRANSLIT --output=$FILE_PATH.tmp $FILE_PATH
    mv $FILE_PATH.tmp $FILE_PATH
}

input=$1
output=$2
./csv_to_xml.py --csv $input --output  $output
convertFileEncoding $output ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-8
```

Neither ways have worked. When I open the output file in `gvim` and `:set enc=iso-8859-8` I get messed up stuff instead of hebrew letters

Hope you can help me fix that

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Running `.encode()` and `.decode()` will yield different exceptions. It's probably best not to lump them together - knowing the exact exception and stacktrace will let people better understand the problem

Comment: Due to the way encoding works it's very difficult to detect the difference between code pages and character sets without language analysis - `file` is just making the best guess.

Comment: What data type is `data`? Assuming you're using Python 2.x, is it a Unicode str or a regular str? If it's a regular str, what encoding is it in? Where did `data` come from?

Comment: Knowing all the answer will allow you to know whether you should be using `decode()` or `encode()` rather than just using it willy-nilly.

Comment: data is a csv file that I read from the file system. By now, I've come to suspect the the original file, which I'm trying to generate from, has messed up encoding, as I've tried all the methods I found on SO and some advice and source code examples of workmates, and it still hasn't worked. My problem now is that I need the get the source file to a decent encoding, and I'm not having much success at that either. I need the result to be `ISO-8859-8` and the hebrew in it should be shown correctly. So far all that I've achieved is garbage strings instead of hebrew :X

Comment: What encoding is the original csv file?

Comment: `file -i` states `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: but it contains Hebrew characters? As I've already said, it's difficult for apps to guess encoding - `א` in iso-8895-8 = `E0` = `à` in iso-8895-1. How does `file` know which mapping to use? It can't. As it looks like you're on Windows, open the source file in Notepad++. Notepad++ has some advanced language analysis to detect encoding. See what encoding yields the correct result

Comment: Actually I'm on Linux, `Debian 8` to be exact. When I open the file in `gvim`, the hebrew seems correct, but when I use `:set enc=iso-8859-8` the hebrew gets messed up badly, with characters like `~U` and `~T` and stuff like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115412/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-giora-guttsait).

Answer (score 0):

Errors like `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position ...` usually show up when your source file isn't really encoded like you could think it is.

To make sure your file is encoded as ISO-8859-1 you can check it with [Python module named **chardet**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), which is installable by pip and really easy to use.